# Ruby gems not recognized in bash script

Tags: bash, ruby, node.js, gem

I have built a node.js app that listens for webhooks. Currently it is used to build a jekyll website.

I have configured it on my server and `jekyll build` works perfectly when I run it in the root of my jekyll website (which is sending the hooks). When I run the node.js app over ssh in a shell everything works fine as well when a git hook is triggered.

However, when the node.js app is run from an upstart script (shown below) it doesn't seem to find the gems. It keeps asking for dependencies which I am sure I have installed (globally as well as for my user).

Inside the script I have put `` echo`which jekyll` `` and this shows that it is indeed pointing to the locally installed `jekyll` bin: `/home/christophe/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/jekyll`. But right below that I execute the jekyll command and it fails:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 31 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /home/christophe/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

How can I execute this bash script to properly execute jekyll?

## Upstart

```
# /etc/init/libservice.conf
# Task to automatically start the library service.

author "Christophe De Troyer"
description "Run the githook for the blog."

# Path of the configuration files
env PROJ="/home/christophe/jekyll-builder"

# Configure to run as `christophe`
setuid christophe
setgid christophe

script
    export PATH=/home/christophe/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin:$PATH
    cd $PROJ
    gulp run
end script    

start on startup
#Respawn the process if it crashes
#If it respawns more than 10 times in 5 seconds stop
respawn limit 10 5
```

## Build script

```
#!/bin/bash                                            

########################                               
# Parameters from Node #                               
########################                               

giturl=$1                                              
reponame=$2                                            
branch=$3                                              
ownermail=$4                                           
reporoot=$5                                            
htmlsink=$6                                            
www=$7                                                 

##########                                             
# Script #                                             
##########                                             

# Check to see if reponame exists. If not, git clone it
if [ ! -d $reporoot ]; then                            
    mkdir -p $reporoot                                 
    git clone $giturl $reporoot                        
fi                                                     

# Checkout and pull branch.                            
cd $reporoot                                           
git checkout $branch                                   
git pull origin $branch                                
cd -                                                   


echo `which jekyll` 
jekyll # fails                                   
# Run jekyll                                           
jekyll build -s $reporoot -d $htmlsink    # fails too
```

Update:

`gem env` while logged in as a user:

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-01-12 patchlevel 384) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.0
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.0.0
     - /home/christophe/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.0.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

`gem env` from within the script, executed from the node.js app running via upstart gives:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-01-12 patchlevel 384) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.0
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.0.0
     - /.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.0.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Notice that the `GEM_PATHS` is missing the home directory prefix in the second entry. I have tried resolving this by putting `env GEM_PATH="/home/christophe/.gem/ruby/2.0.0"` in the upstart script but that didnt change anything.

In the meanwhile I have solved it by intalling a list of deps manually as root. However, I don't think this is a good approach as the upstart is explicitly running as my user. And secondly, this software needs to run on a server I don't have root permissions on. So I would still like to know a fix.

```
sudo gem install jekyll
sudo gem install jekyll-gist
sudo gem install jekyll-cite
sudo gem install jekyll-scholar
sudo gem install addressable -v 2.3.5
sudo gem install yajl-ruby -v 1.2.0
sudo gem install pygments.rb
sudo gem install posix-spawn
```

Comment: The "GEM PATHS" bit is lacking the home directory path under upstart, so that would be one thing to look at--how does gem set that?

Comment: Yes, I have added that in the end. `/.gem/` is not a valid path so I assume that it is meant to be my user gem path, but somehow it is missing the prefix.

Comment: Your build process is likely failing to `source` the same files that an interactive login does, it could be `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_aliases`, etc... ya may have the `GEM_HOME` environment variable and related `PATH` variable modifications _stashed away_ within one of these files; see a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157908/2632107) for the start of a _bread crumb_ trail that goes into more detail... What happens if ya add something like _`export GEM_HOME="${HOME}/.gem"`_ as well as _`export PATH="${GEM_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"`_ near the top of your build script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of agony I have finally fixed it.

The trick was to set the `PATH` to: `/home/cdetroye/.rbenv/shims:/home/cdetroye/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`.

```
# /etc/init/libservice.conf
# Task to automatically start the library service.

author "Christophe De Troyer"
description "Run the githook for the blog."

# Path of the configuration files

env PATH=/home/cdetroye/.rbenv/shims:/home/cdetroye/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

# Configure to run as `christophe`
setuid cdetroye
setgid cdetroye

script
    cd $PROJ
    gulp run
end script    

start on startup
#Respawn the process if it crashes
#If it respawns more than 10 times in 5 seconds stop
respawn limit 10 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `GEM_HOME` environment? I was able to at least get an upstart service listing a custom install dir via something like:

```
cd
gem install rake --install-dir grepable
```

And then using a `/etc/init/footest.conf` service of:

```
author "Nobody"
description "Echo some details"

env GEM_HOME="/home/jdoe/grepable"

setuid jdoe
setgid jdoe

script
    /usr/bin/gem environment
end script    

start on startup
respawn limit 10 5
```

And after a reboot,

```
# fgrep -1 grep /var/log/upstart/footest.log
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jdoe/grepable
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/jdoe/grepable/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
--
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/jdoe/grepable
     - /.gem/ruby/1.9.1
```

For a production service one presumably would use an `--install-dir`/`GEM_HOME` of somewhere suitable not in the vendor space nor your home directory.